# How to configure Resharper to decompile the implementation assemblies, not the empty reference assemblies?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, decompiler

**Context**

I am using VS 2019 with Resharper 2018.3 developing a .NET Asp Core 3 Preview 5 project.

When I ctrl-click (navigate) on an method which is not in my source Resharper decompiles it. Unfortunately Resharper decompiles the empty reference assembly, not the real one. (see decompiled sample below, the `// Assembly location:...` comment line)

**Question**

How can I overcome this issue?

**Sample**

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.EnvironmentTagHelper
// Assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
// MVID: 53BD133B-15D1-407A-8F06-FD367295366C
// Assembly location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\3.0.0-preview5-19227-01\ref\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll
```